# how to implement python program that input given by user will make binary search tree or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I  want to implement this code but I failed many many times. Can any one give me the answer of this code?

```
import sys, threading

sys.setrecursionlimit(10**7) # max depth of recursion
threading.stack_size(2**25)  # new thread will get stack of such size

def IsBinarySearchTree(tree):
  # Implement correct algorithm here

  if tree.right > tree.nodes:
  return True
  if tree.left < tree.nodes:
  return True


def main():
  nodes = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
  tree = []
  for i in range(nodes):
    tree.append(list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())))
  if IsBinarySearchTree(tree):
```

print("CORRECT")
      else:
        print("INCORRECT")

```
  threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

Comment: Most of this code is irrelevant except `# Implement correct algorithm here`. Show us one of the things you tried that didn’t work instead of the skeleton, maybe?

Comment: this code is given by my professor and i have to implement it. if it is irrelavant so give me another code that give me correct output.

Comment: I mean it’s irrelevant to your question. Do you know the algorithm you’re supposed to be implementing?

Answer (score 0):

So I will not be providing you with any code here because this is pretty clearly a HW assignment and it is important to understand this.

A BST is essentially a tree where every element to the left of a given element is less than that element and every thing to the right of a given element is larger than that given element.

One way to go about figuring out if a given tree is a BST is to recursively check the left and right subtrees and check that those subtrees are also BST. To do this you check to see if the left and right subtrees of the subtree is a BST and so on and so forth until you reach the bottom of the tree. Once you have reached the bottom of the tree you can definitively say that a given tree is a BST or not, but you must reach the "bottom" by checking every element in the tree!

I hope this helps you a little in just figuring out how to get started.